# Python - Recursive Functions

Tags: python

Below is the code that I am trying to execute: Recursively parse a string for a pattern that can be either 1 or 2 characters long.

```
def recur_parse(s,pattern):
   result = False
   print(s[0],s[0:2],result)
   if s[0]==pattern or s[0:2]==pattern:
     print('Condition Satisfied')
     return True
   elif len(s[1:]) >= len(pattern):
     print('Calling the function recurisively with params',s[1:],pattern)
     recur_parse(s[1:],pattern)
   else:
     return False
```

The expectation is that the recursive call should return a True, but it returns a False. Am I doing anything wrong?

The testcases execution for the same are below:

Case #1:

```
recur_parse('ximibi','xi')
('x', 'xi', False)
Condition Satisfied
=> True
```

Case #2:

```
recur_parse('ximibi','im')
('x', 'xi', False)
('Calling the function recurisively with params', 'imibi', 'im')
('i', 'im', False)
Condition Satisfied
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not really return a `False`, but it returns `None` in the recursive case. Also, it always prints the initial value of the (never again used) variable `result`, which is `False`. To fix it, just add a `return` statement before the recursive call.

```
def recur_parse(s, pattern):
    if s[0] == pattern or s[0:2] == pattern:
        return True
    elif len(s[1:]) >= len(pattern):
        return recur_parse(s[1:], pattern)
    else:
        return False
```

You could also simplify the function to a single, more complex `return` statement (though whether that's simpler is certainly a matter of taste).

```
def recur_parse(s, pattern):
    return s[0] == pattern or s[0:2] == pattern \
            or len(s[1:]) >= len(pattern) and recur_parse(s[1:],pattern)
```

Comment: Thank you Tobi..didn't notice that I did figure that out after I posted it. Also your approach on it is great! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your second case isn't returning `False`, it is returning `None` because you are not returning the result of the recursive call to `recur_parse`. Compare your code to the following function:

```
def recur_parse(s, pattern):
   if s[0] == pattern or s[0:2] == pattern:
     return True
   elif len(s[1:]) >= len(pattern):
     return recur_parse(s[1:], pattern) # notice the return here
   else:
     return False
```

However, this only works with patterns that are of length 1 or 2. This can be extended with `str.startswith`.

```
def has_string(s, m):
    return s.startswith(m) or bool(s) and has_string(s[1:], m)
```

Note that here `bool(s)` is the base case. Whether or not this is readable is above my pay grade.

If this wasn't a practice in recursion, you'd want to use:

```
def has_string(s, m):
    return m in s
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Jared, it was more of practice in recursion. You response is helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def recur_parse(s,pattern):
    if (len(s) < len(pattern)):
        return False
    if (s[0:len(pattern)] == pattern):
        return True
    return recur_parse(s[1:],pattern)
```

Changed so it is slightly more robust: Should work with patterns of n length.

1. You should be returning the result of the recursive function so you know the result further down the line.
2. Your `Result` variable does nothing
3. You should probably check the length at the start of the function in case a String shorter than the pattern is passed to begin with
4. You can remove one of the conditional statements with the position of the return statements.

The first part of the recursive statement checks for the edge cases: Where you either **know**, explicitly, that the String is valid or invalid. Finally, the recursive step assumes that the two edge cases failed, hence try again until one passes.

Comment: Thank you Zachary. Your approach is more generic and helpful.